# Gnome-shell Only Shows Wallpaper

Tags: 12.10, gnome, lubuntu

So, I just installed gnome-shell on my Lubuntu 12.10.
After I logged in with Gnome, it just stay there showing only wallpaper and my cursor and no, I cannot open a terminal emulator from there. Ctrl-alt-t didn't worked.

What should I do to fix this?

Btw, this is my xsession-errors log

```
(gnome-settings-daemon:6643): color-plugin-WARNING **: There is no colord server available

(gnome-shell:6669): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(gnome-shell:6669): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion  `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
gnome-session[6590]: WARNING: Application 'gnome-shell.desktop' killed by signal 11

(gnome-shell:6680): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(gnome-shell:6680): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion   `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
gnome-session[6590]: WARNING: Application 'gnome-shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
gnome-session[6590]: WARNING: App 'gnome-shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
gnome-session[6590]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

(nm-applet:6697): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nm-applet:6697): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(gnome-user-share:7003): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(gnome-user-share:7003): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

** (zeitgeist-datahub:7009): WARNING **: recent-manager-provider.vala:133: Desktop file  for "file:///usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers/1210-Sunset_by_Luca_Andrea_Rossi.jpg" was not  found, exec: lxpanel, mime_type: image/jpeg

(update-notifier:7037): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(update-notifier:7037): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(gnome-settings-daemon:6643): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11  (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

blueman-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

** (zeitgeist-datahub:7009): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name      "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
```

Comment: you can almost always open a terminal emulator with ctl-alt-f1 or f2.  the rest of your argument is pretty valid though

Comment: Stupid me, I mean the GUI terminal emulator (does this even make sense?) that you usually called with Ctrl-alt-t. So what is happening exactly? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to install gnome-shell on Lubuntu. Instead you should consider installing Ubuntu GNOME if your computer hardware is compatible with the Ubuntu GNOME system requirements. According to the [Ubuntu GNOME wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME):

***"System Requirements***

*It is recommended to have at least 1 GB of RAM or more (we shall soon do re-assessment for further specific details). If you have an old machine, you may consider other alternatives like Lubuntu."*

If the reason why you want to install gnome-shell in Lubuntu is to have an interface customized for netbooks, you should consider installing the *lxlauncher* package from the default Ubuntu repositories. Lxlauncher is an add-on for the LXDE Desktop Environment on which Lubuntu is based as its default GUI. From the description of lxlauncher in the Ubuntu Software Center: *"...Easy-Mode launcher for netbooks like EeePC"*.

Comment: All right, purge it then. I was just wanted to try gnome, and since I use Lubuntu atm so...